# Images disapear in rails app (s3 setup done)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I just set up my rails app, it's almost done, I did the s3 bucket so that the images uploaded by paperclip won't disapear from the website, and yet after a short time they disapear and i don't know why. I'm definitely a beginner in dev, and even more with s3, but i followed the guiledines pretty thoroughly, with the help of a dev, and I put the access key id, bucket name, region and secret access key in the heroku dashboard.
I don't know what part of the code to show, or what images from the s3 management console to show to get some help, but if anyone knows potentially what to do it'll be so much apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you setup s3?

Comment: yep I made a bucket and added the required info in the settings of heroku. I didn't change anything in the code though, but it looks ok to me.

Comment: Can you show us the content of config/initializers/paperclip.rb and the code for the template that's used to display the image to the user after it's been uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) the article I followed.

Comment: Everything in my code is conform to what is in that article